# onSensorChanged() is not called

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

I'm having a lot of trouble tonight with sensors, but it appear it is because of onSensorChanged() is not called. Sorry for the eventual duplicate question, but I didn't see any solutions.
Here's my code :

```
public SensorManager manager;
public Sensor rotation_vector;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    manager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    rotation_vector = manager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    int xValue = (int) event.values[0];
    int yValue = (int) event.values[1];
    int zValue = (int) event.values[2];
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"this doesn't appear...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);


@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    //TODO: we'll see later about it
}
public void onPause() {
        /*Et on le dés-enregistre quand on sort de l'activité, pour économiser de la batterie*/
        super.onPause();
        manager.unregisterListener(this);
}
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        /*On enregistre le sensor quand l'utilisateur revient sur l'activité*/
        super.onResume();
        manager.registerListener(this, rotation_vector, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        if (null != rotation_vector) {
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "There is no gyroscope on your device",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

I have seen a lot of similar code on different forums, but appart from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095069/onsensorchanged-not-called) and some others topic without solutions, I haven't seen such a problem yet...
Do I have to add something in AndroidManifest ?
Is it a common problem ?
It there a solution ?

Thanks, 
Thomas
*(sorry for my bad english, I'm French^^)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was not working with Sensors so far, but it looks like you have obtained `SensorManager` but did not register any listener for changes that should occur. Just ask yourself how could be `onSensorChanged` called?

Have a look at the sample on [official android tutorial site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html#sensors-monitor) about sensors and you could see this in `onResume()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mLight, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}
```

Also don't forget to study whole page it can help you a lot.

**Edit:**

I had to copy paste your sources because I haven't seen any problem. There are 2 basicaly:

- Toast is not appearing because you haven't told him to... `Toast.show()` will display it. But you rather use `Log` to output changes into console. It's up to you
- Do not retype float into int in `onSensorChanged()` method because all values are 0 or (1/-1 if you are lucky)

So result is following:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float xValue = event.values[0];
    float yValue = event.values[1];
    float zValue = event.values[2];
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "x:"+xValue +";y:"+yValue+";z:"+zValue);
}
```

other methods are correct

Comment: Well, I forgot that part of my code, it was at the bottom... It doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Please update your question then, I'm pretty sure it have to work... Also try non null checks. If it is not working I'll take a deeper look later

Comment: Done ! What do you call by "non null checks " ?

Comment: I meant exactly those which mentioned @hoan-nguyen in other answer

Comment: How do I do that ? Sorry I'm new :x

Comment: Click on grey Checkmark next to my answer right below number indicating "likes"

Answer (score 1):

Your device probably does not have `Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR`. You should check `rotation_vector` for `null`.

Comment: I used an app listing every sensor on the device and displaying their data. And the rotation vector sensor worked well

Comment: Register for TYPE_GYROSCOPE also and see if TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR is now called.