# How to get Android Device's orientation programatically, api 23+

Tags: android, android-sensors

[Simple orientation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVfi1.jpg)

As in the picture, I want to get the pitch, that is, I want to check whether the device is parallel to the ground.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291322/what-is-the-alternative-to-android-orientation-sensor/10291428#10291428 this will help you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175599/how-to-measure-the-tilt-of-the-phone-in-xy-plane-using-accelerometer-in-android/15149421#15149421

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I register the Orientation like this:

```
 sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
 sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
```

and compared the values (in `onSensorChanged`) to the ones that the sensor would give if the phone was placed parallel to the ground.

Comment: WARNING Orientation Sensor was deprecated 7 years ago ;-)

Answer (score 0):

use the following code snippet it works fine...

```
private boolean isLandscape()
{
return Activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;

}
```

Comment: I don't want to check if its landscape or now (if that's what this snippet is doing), I want to e.g, ring an alert if my device is put on a table since that would be 'parallel to the ground'.

Answer (score -1):

Try this to get device orientation

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE